# Combining two Oracle SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine 2 query conditions in one SQL statement. I am unable to logically combine them.

1) Employee whose leave is approved by manager

```
select e.employee_name,r.request_from_Date,r.request_to_Date from  employee_leave e,emp_leave_request r
 where e.employee_id=r.request_from_id and e.employee_manager_id= r.request_to_id
 and r.request_Approved_date is not null
 and r.request_reject_Date is null
 and r.request_cancelled_Date is null;
```

2) Employee who is part of manager's team

```
 select employee_id, employee_name, employee_email, employee_username, employee_leave_normal, employee_contact_no,employee_designation
from employee_leave a
where exists(select 1 from employee_leave b where lower(b.employee_username)=lower(:APP_USER) and a.employee_manager_id=b.employee_id);
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i had to submit my project and this was the only thing hindering. i had to submit it today only thats why the urgency. although will keep in mind not to mention these words again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN to achieve the same.Please learn what is an INNER join [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

```
        SELECT     e1.*,
               e.request_from_date,
               e.request_to_date
    FROM       (
                      SELECT e.employee_id,
                             e.employee_name,
                             r.request_from_date,
                             r.request_to_date
                      FROM   employee_leave e,
                             emp_leave_request r
                      WHERE  e.employee_id=r.request_from_id
                      AND    e.employee_manager_id= r.request_to_id
                      AND    r.request_approved_date IS NOT NULL
                      AND    r.request_reject_date IS NULL
                      AND    r.request_cancelled_date IS NULL)e
    inner join
               (
                      SELECT employee_id,
                             employee_name,
                             employee_email,
                             employee_username,
                             employee_leave_normal,
                             employee_contact_no,
                             employee_designation
                      FROM   employee_leave a
                      WHERE  EXISTS
                             (
                                    SELECT 1
                                    FROM   employee_leave b
                                    WHERE  Lower(b.employee_username)=Lower(:APP_USER)
                                    AND    a.employee_manager_id=b.employee_id) e1
                      ON e.employee_id=e1.employee_id
```

Comment: There is no specific directive on Stack Overflow against doing peoples' work for them. Indeed some people encourage it on the basis that the answer might be useful for future developers. But consider that if the question author is a beginner, they will not learn much by having their work done for them, and they might get into the habit of asking Stack Overflow helpers to do their work every time they decide that personal effort is too much for them.

Comment: asked OP to learn about INNER JOIN with a link,please let me know what more can be done so beginners can learn to do themselves next time

Comment: Personally, I would refrain from answering at all until the question author has shown some personal effort. If they are unwilling to show any effort after prompting them with a comment, don't help them.

Answer (score 0):

Use union to combine 2 sql select queries
example:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp